Are there any reasons to keep scanned film frames as tiff files with RGB 24 and more bit?
I scan films with Primefilm 3600u scanner by Vuescan software. The software has option of autosaving of scanning results to tiff files, having 24 or more bit depth. The same is possible for raw files. The films are corrupted, have a lot scratches, many of them and photos have bad quality. There is scanner matrix defect also. It shows itself on a lot of images. The samples are included here. That is why I plan to order deletion of scratches, spots and other defects. The images will be looked at 32 diagonal tv or at home cinema at least 49 inches. Please write me your opinion about the reason to keep tiff files with 24, 48 RGB or 64 rgbi.​

At least 48-bit RGB will allow you to make adjustments to color balance and brightness curves after the scan without introducing any banding.  Vuescan's IR dust/scratch removal isn't always great on every scanner so recording the infrared channel as well would give you a ready made mask for doing dust removal in your editor of choice. These are all with the assumption you are printing later.
If you are fully satisfied with the output from just Vuescan then there's no reason to record more than a 24-bit JPEG, except that you might want to print it later.
Vuescan also has the ability to save unprocessed scans as 'raw tiff' files.  This way they can be run back into Vuescan and reprocessed later.  Vuescan can also output multiple kinds of files at the same time. So you could output size-reduced and processed JPEGs for viewing while keeping raw scans as an archive for later reprocessing.
